# Keep getting error in trying to INSERT into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I keep getting the same error everytime I try to INSERT data into a MySQL table in my Python script:

```
tools.cerabot@tools-login:~/wikitool-tasks2$ python didyouknow.py
didyouknow.py:62: Warning: Table 'did_you_know' already exists
  self.cursor.execute(self.create_query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "didyouknow.py", line 121, in <module>
    test._parse_page()
  File "didyouknow.py", line 109, in _parse_page
    self.cursor.execute(record_exists.format(item["name"]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':Did you know nominations/Cirrus (song)' at line 1")
```

The code for this is openly viewable on [GitHub](https://github.com/ceradon/wikitool-tasks/blob/master/didyouknow.py), though you'd be particularly interested in lines [95](https://github.com/ceradon/wikitool-tasks/blob/master/didyouknow.py#L95) through 116. I've tried escaping and unicoding the string, modifying my query, nothing. (Admittedly, I'm a basic MySQL programmer.) Could anyone experienced in the area help me figure this out please?

Comment: What is the value of `item["name"]` when this error occurs?

Comment: @Joseph item["name"] is a wikipedia article title. They come in all shapes and sizes, funny characters abound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "funny characters" in your Wikipedia titles are messing with the SQL syntax. You need to handle that. This can be done by escaping, but the best practice is to use SQL parameterization, like so:

```
record_exists = u"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM did_you_know WHERE " \
                "name = %s"
# and later on
self.cursor.execute(record_exists, item["name"])
```

You're actually already doing this later on (line 112).